# WPF button, content to reach the sides

Tags: wpf, data-binding

So I have a button on a window in a grid column. The button is shown below:

```
<Button>
    <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Width}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Background="LightBlue">bunnies</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Width}" Background="LightBlue">bunnies</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Button>
```

What I see is the example in the left most button below, I'd like it to look like 2 below.

EDIT:
If you add a Width="1000" to the first TextBlock, you will see the effect I want, except that then the text is not central to the column any more, it's central to a block 1000 wide. So what I am after is the binding syntax of the actual column width or the actual button width.

I've left in some of the things that I've tried, changing the Width of a single column definition, binding stuff, all sorts.

[image: Left = 1 Right = 2]

Ignore the dodgy editing on the text, I just want the border to reach the edge of the button. 
Thanks

Comment: So you want to stretch the text if it's not long enough?

Comment: Sorry, no, that's my bad MSPaint skills. Ignore the text, if the text is short I still want the border to fit the width of the column. You can fake it by setting Width of the TextBlock to an actual number, but I can't find out how to bind to the actual width of the button.

Comment: Added an edit, hopefully that's a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">bunnies</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">bunnies</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Perfect. I love it when the answer is straight forward :) I'm not sure why, but I find the intellisense a little odd in WPF. Just checked, here's what's going on. If I name the button, and in code start typing "AButton.Alig" it gives me the four different alignments as options. It doesn't do that in the WPF editor. Might feed that back to the resharper people, unless it's just me doing it wrong :)